# Defining constants in laravel

Tags: laravel, constants

In laravel, there is no constant file defined, so I went on and searched for a way to implement the use of constants. The method below is what I managed to put together:

```
// app/config/constants.php
return['CONSTANT_NAME' => 'value'];

// index.blade.php
{{ Config::get('constants.CONSTANT_NAME') }}
```

Now, my question is; is there a cleaner way of retrieving my constants in my view? Something like:

```
{{ Constant::get('CONSTANT_NAME') }}
```

This is in order to keep my view nice, short and clean.

Appreciate the input!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One thing you can do is to [share pieces of data across](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#views) your views:

```
View::share('my_constant', Config::get('constants.CONSTANT_NAME'));
```

Put that at the top of your `routes.php` and the constant will then be accessible in all your blade views as:

```
{{ $my_constant }}
```

Comment: Ha! Not sure why I didnt think of this at all, especially since I am familiar with Laravel's share functionality!

Answer (score 4):

The `Config` class is intended to replace the need for constants and serves the same role.

Have `app/config/constants.php` return an array of key/value pairs, then just use `Config::get('constants.key')` to access them.

You could conceivably create a `Constant` class that has a `get` function as a shortcut:

```
class Constant {
  public function get($key) {
    return Config::get('constants.' . $key);
  }
}
```

but using the standard Laravel handling is likely to be nicer to other Laravel developers trying to familiarize themselves with your code.

Answer (score 2):

In v5 you can do like @msturdy suggests except you store the constant in the .env file or in production as actual $_ENVIRONMENT variables on your server for your environment.

Example .env entry:

```
CONSTANT=value
```

Then call like so:

```
View::share('bladeConstant', env('CONSTANT'));
```

Then load it with:

```
{{ bladeConstant }}
```

Comment: .env is not recommended for use in production environments (https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv#usage-notes), it can behave unpredictably (and for that reason I'd say isn't even that useful in development!).

Comment: True, however the environment variables can also be set on your server instead of using a .env file. and the rest of the above remains the same. I've updated my answer to reflect this better.