# What is the best practice for adding constants in laravel? (Long List)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, constants, laravel-5.3

I am rather new to laravel. I have a basic question, What is the best way to add constants in laravel. 
I know the .env method that we use to add the constants. 
Also I have made one constants file to use them for my project. 
For example:

```
define('OPTION_ATTACHMENT', 13);
define('OPTION_EMAIL', 14);
define('OPTION_MONETERY', 15);
define('OPTION_RATINGS', 16);
define('OPTION_TEXTAREA', 17);
```

And so on. It can reach upto 100 or more records. So What should be the best approach to write the constants. The .env method. Or adding the constant.php file?

Thanks

Comment: you can choose a lot of places: 1) a regular (my)SQL db 2) a key-value story / nosql db like redis 3) the config folder, using your own config file and probably many more. Best practice would be probably option 3 and also the fastest

Comment: Maybe this answer can be useful for you :http://stackoverflow.com/a/26062788/6028607

Comment: @VincentG like I have explained above. I dont think .env is the best choice. I have a long list of constants.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: Where to store global arrays data and constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854030/laravel-where-to-store-global-arrays-data-and-constants)

Comment: Your accepted answer does not align with your question or example. A constant is not a config variable that will change. It is exactly how it is labeled, a constant value that does not change no matter what. The answer given by @Neekobus is the correct approach for constants. You may want to revise the accepted answer.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

For most constants used globally across the application, storing them in config files is sufficient. It is also pretty simple

Create a new file in the `config` directory. Let's call it `constants.php`

In there you have to return an array of config values.

```
return [
    'options' => [
        'option_attachment' => '13',
        'option_email' => '14',
        'option_monetery' => '15',
        'option_ratings' => '16',
        'option_textarea' => '17',
    ]
];
```

And you can access them as follows

```
config('constants.options');
// or if you want a specific one
config('constants.options.option_attachment');
```

Comment: the directory is actually `/config`

Comment: @KArunSingh why didnt you just point to duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854030/laravel-where-to-store-global-arrays-data-and-constants .

Comment: `in mathematics, the adjective constant means non-varying` which means this is not the "correct answer"

Comment: remember to run `php artisan config:cache` after adding the constants.php file

Comment: Also I think it should be `\Config::get('constants.options');` or `\Config::get('constants.options.option_attachment');` with backslash

Comment: Either use `\Config::get` or write on top of the class `use Config`

Comment: One can also call it with the `config` helper `config('constants.options');`

Comment: If I'm understanding the question, you're not asking about configuration variables. You're asking about defining constants which are a way to remove magic numbers and strings https://stackoverflow.com/a/3518945/3738956 from your code. I don't think the config files are a place to do this. I recommend the answer by @Neekobus https://stackoverflow.com/a/50276442/3738956 of using "Aliased class constants" I think they fit your question much better.

Comment: Instead of using "::get()", just use config('constants.options') or config('constants.options.option_attachment');

Make sure in the above solutions I have not used first letter capital with "::get()".

Answer (score 123):

I use aliased class constants :

First, create your class that contain your constants : `App/MyApp.php` for exemple

```
namespace App;

class MyApp {
   const MYCONST = 'val';
}
```

Then add it to the aliased classes in the `config/app.php`

```
'aliases' => [
  //...
  'MyApp' => App\MyApp::class,
```

Finally use them wherever you like (controllers or even blades) :

```
MyApp::MYCONST
```

Comment: I like this approach. This will help other developers to easily track where constants are coming from instead of declaring it to your auto load. Is there any drawback of using this approach?

Comment: For constants, I can't see any drawbacks. 
For config (changing with environment) is not fitted. Use Config:get instead.

Comment: This is a better and faster option than the "accepted answer" thanks!

Comment: like that approach as well (just remind of using `composer dump-autoload` after the changes

Comment: Does all of this still hold true in Laravel (currently v9)? Would you still put it in the root of `app`? With the subfolders of `Console`, `Exceptions`, `Http`, `Providers`, `Services`, & `View`, none really seem to apply?!?

Comment: @wruckie Typically people will make a subfolder under `app` called `Support` for this type of stuff.

Comment: I was able to get code like this running in Views, but not in my Controllers. I had to use `using App\MyConst` class import. Is that normal? That does not agree with @Neekobus last statement.

Answer (score 21):

Your question was about the 'best practices' and you asked about the '.env method'.

.env is only for variables that change because the **environment** changes. Examples of different environments: test, acceptance, production.

So the .env contains database credentials, API keys, etc.

The .env should (imho) never contain constants which are the same over all environments. Just use the suggested config files for that.

Comment: Yup... Makes sense...

Answer (score 18):

First you make `Constants` folder inside your app directory.

And then you make `Constants.php`. Define your constants in this file

For Example :

```
define('ONE', '1');
define('TWO', '2');
```

And you modify the `composer.json`

Alternatively, you can use composer.json to load the bootstrap/constants.php file by adding the following code to the “autoload” section, like so:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "bootstrap/constants.php"
    ]
}
```

And update your composer !

Comment: It would be good if write as defined('ONE') || define('ONE', '1');

Answer (score 17):

You can create a file named **paths.php** in **root directory/config/paths.php**

Insert this data into paths.php

```
define('OPTION_ATTACHMENT', 13);
define('OPTION_EMAIL', 14);
define('OPTION_MONETERY', 15);
define('OPTION_RATINGS', 16);
define('OPTION_TEXTAREA', 17);
```

Note : make sure to run command : `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: Why `paths.php`? Seems pretty random.

Answer (score 14):

I think you should not have a single place for all your constants. Especially no file called `constance.php`.

I use PHP constance in classes and refer to them in code, so its more readable, typically to avoid magic numbers and typos in strings

```
Car::where('car_type','=', 'fast_car')->get();
```

and rather have

```
Car::where('car_type','=', CarType::FAST)->get();
```

If its a value that depends on your environment (like email setting, should be different local vs production), then you should add it to a matching files in the config folder (e.g. '/config/mail.php'). You may also just add a new file in the config folder. A config file returns an array, so it could look like this:

```
<?php

return [
  'your_option' => env('YOUR_OPTION')
];
```

and you can read it using the config helper:

```
config('your_config_file.your_option');
```

Its important to never call the `env` function outside a configuration file, as the env function returns null outside a configuration file when cache is enabled.

If the option does not rely on your environment, you can just add it directly to the matching config file.

```
<?php

return [
  'your_option' => 10
];
```

Answer (score 14):

I would personally create a class for that.

```
<?php

namespace App\Transaction\Constants;

/**
 * Class TransactionTypeConstant.
 */
final class TransactionTypeConstant
{
    public const TYPE_CREDIT = 'CREDIT';
    public const TYPE_DEBIT = 'DEBIT';
}
```

and use it like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Transaction;

use App\Transaction\Constants\TransactionTypeConstant;

class Transaction
{
    /**
     * Execute the task.
     *
     * @return object
     */
    public function run()
    {
        if ($transaction->type === TransactionTypeConstant::TYPE_DEBIT) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach will works for all. However in this case configs are not cacheble.

Comment: I like this solution because it looks clean and works for all scenarios.

Comment: for me this is the best way to do it, simple and elegant, thanks

Comment: @edocollado Since you posted that after it released, 8.1 provides proper enum support that could be used for this same syntax. They're a bit tighter in focus and may be better for this than conventional classes with constants.

Answer (score 11):

Another way as following:

1. create the constant.php file in app/config directory
2. in composer.json file, add the directives like this:

   ```
   "autoload": {
      "classmap": [
          "database/seeds",
          "database/factories"
      ],
      "psr-4": {
          "App\\": "app/"
      },
      "files": [
          "app/helpers.php",
          "app/config/constants.php"
      ]
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this:

1. Put your constants to 'config/app.php' on main array, like:

   ```
   'CONSTANT_NAME' => 'CONSTANT_VALUE',
   ```
2. Use them where ever you want with:

   ```
   {{ Config::get('CONSTANT_NAME') }}
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can define constants at the top of the web.php file located in routes and can be access the constants anywhere in project  with just constant name

```
define('OPTION_ATTACHMENT', 13);
define('OPTION_EMAIL', 14);
define('OPTION_MONETERY', 15);
define('OPTION_RATINGS', 16);
define('OPTION_TEXTAREA', 17);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require app_path().'/constants.php';

define('ADMIN',  'administrator');
```

or  -

> You can also move more sensitive info

```
return [
   'hash_salt' => env('HASH_SALT'),
 ];
```

And use it like before:

```
 echo Config::get('constants.hash_salt');
```

Answer (score 0):

i think best way to define constant using a helper file. check my solution.

> Define file path in **composer.json**

```
   "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/helpers.php",
            "app/Helper/function.php"  // constant defined here
        ],
```

> app/Helper/**function.php**

```
define("assetPath","UI/");
define("viewPath","UI/");
```

> use this constant anywhere in project. i am using in blade file.

```
  <script src="{{asset(assetPath.'js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
  <script src="{{asset(assetPath.'js/popper.min.js')}}"></script>
  <script src="{{asset(assetPath.'js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
```

> my approach is better than this

```
Config::get('constants.options');
Config::get('constants.options.option_attachment');
```

**here another problem is this , you have to run cache:clear or  cache command for this. but my approach not required this**.