# How to use constant value inside blade file - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, constants, config, laravel-blade

I want to use constant value inside `blade` file.
I have `svg` tag in which I have`<path>` tag in which I want to use constant value.

I searched it online. I got this solution
I got these solutions.

https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/php/get+constant+value+in+laravel
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42155879/7290043

As suggested in the solution. I created a `constants.php`

```dart
<?php
return [

    // -------------- UI Constants
    
    'MAXIMIZE_SQAURE_ICON' => 'M14,15h-4v-2h3v-3h2v4C15,14.6,14.6,15,14,15z M13,3h-3V1h4c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1v4h-2V3z M6,3H3v3H1V2c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1h4V3z
    M3,13h3v2H2c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1v-4h2V13z'
];
```

I'm trying to use this `MAXIMIZE_SQAURE_ICON` value as `d` of `<path>` tag of blade file

```dart
<svg width="16" height="16">
  <path d="MAXIMIZE_SQAURE_ICON" /> 
</svg>
```

I also tried `<path d = Config::get('constants.ADMIN_NAME') />`

I'm not sure how to access it properly. I'm new to laravel.

Comment: You should use: `Config::get('constants.MAXIMIZE_SQAURE_ICON')`

Comment: I used it like this inside path tag `<path d=Config::get('constants.MAXIMIZE_SQAURE_ICON') />`  stil not working

Comment: you will need to use `{{Config::get('constants.MAXIMIZE_SQAURE_ICON')}}` otherwise it is considered as a normal string and not as php code. 
You can read more about how to display data in blade files here:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#displaying-data

Comment: If you just want a reusable icon, would it not make more sense to just drop the whole thing into a Blade component rather than mucking about with constants? Then you could just use something like `<x-icons.max-square />`

Comment: @CD001 perfect. I'm new. I didn't know about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to call the constant in curly braces in your blade file like this:

```
<svg width="16" height="16">
  <path d="{{ config('constants.MAXIMIZE_SQAURE_ICON') }}" /> 
</svg>
```